# Need to package up a couple local, executable files on Arch Linux and be able to install them on another Arch Linux machine

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pkgbuild

I have been researching PKGBUILD and makepkg, but I cannot seem to figure out how to simply make a package with already built, local executable files. I need to package them up so that I can easily install them on another Linux machine. I am using Arch Linux.

I basically need to take two executable files from a specific directory, make a package with those files, and then be able to install those files on another Arch Linux machine in the same location that pacman would normally install executables. Not use any source code or anything because the apps are already built.

I know to put the files in the source spot in the PKGBUILD file, but what do I put in the package() function, and do I need a .install file? If so, what do I need in there?

EDIT: This question has been resolved. The best answer has been marked.

Comment: Put the files in the `source` array in the PKGBUILD.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks for your response. Yes, but then what do I put in the package function, and do I need an install file? If so, what do I need to put in it.

Comment: You only need an install file (or hook) if you have to run some script pre- or post installation. In the `package` function, you just install the pkg in the relevant directory (look at some similar packages in the repos for examples).

Comment: @jasonwryan I appreciate the help. Any advice on finding a good example repo out of the many that are there?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what it is that you are actually trying to do, so I can't help much more than I have. Any package which installs a simple executable would probably suffice.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, I was just wondering if there was an easy way to search through them all to find one that installs a simple executable, but it doesn't look like there's a great way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages can ship with arbitrary files that sit in the same directory as the PKGBUILD file. For your purposes, you can do just that. Within the PKGBUILD file's `package()` function, you can refer to those files as `${srcdir}/my-executable`. The end result might look like this:

```bsh
# snip!
source=(my-executable)
sha256sums=('foo')

package() {
  install -Dm755 "${srcdir}/my-executable" "${pkgdir}/usr/local/bin/my-executable"
}
```

You can now make a package with:

```
updpkgsums && mksrcinfo && makepkg
```

Note that this approach is only really appropriate for homebrew packages. Do **not** take this approach if uploading packages to the AUR. The files that ship alongside your PKGBUILD should change infrequently - certainly not with every release. And if your executable is a binary, you will be disallowed from uploading your package to the AUR. (Or it'll work, and someone will find it and ban you.)

For a concrete example, check out [mkgmap](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mkgmap/). It installs a simple wrapper script to `/usr/bin/mkgmap`. Note that I'm using a few anachronisms, like executing `cd "${srcdir}/${pkgname}-${pkgver}"` at the head of `package()`.

Once you've created a package, there are several tools available for getting those packages to all your hosts. One nice application-specific tool is [pacserve](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacserve). (Thanks to jasonwryan for the tip.)

Also, consider looking in to a tool like Ansible. If you want the package manager to know about these executables, making a package is great. But if you want to place files in user directories like `~/.local/bin/`, configuration management systems may serve you better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! May I ask what the -Dm755 is?

Comment: It's a concise way of writing out `-D -m 755`. For the exact meaning of the options, see install(1). (Run `man 1 install`, or find the man page [online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install).)

Comment: @jasonwryan Done.